# Feige Fiat Shamir Scheme not working

Tags: c, algorithm, math, cryptography, arduino

I'm trying to implement the *Feige Fiat Shamir Identification Scheme* in C (Arduino) and it works, but only when `e = 0`. When `e = 1` it doesn't work.

**How can I make it work?**

```
#include <Wire.h>

int getGCD(int a, int b)
{
   int c;
   while (a != 0)
   {
      c = a;
      a = b % a;
      b = c;
   }
   return b;
}

int getCoprime(int n)
{
   int coprime;
   do
   {
      coprime = random(1, n);
   } 
   while (getGCD(n, coprime) != 1);
   return coprime;
}


//Preparation
int n = 7 * 3;
int s = getCoprime(n);
int v = (s * s) % n;

void loop ()
{
  e = random(0, 2);
  r = random(1, n);
  int y = (r * (int)pow(s, e)) % n;
  int x = (r * r) % n;

  int ysqmodn = y * y % n;
  int test = (x * (int)pow(v, e)) % n;

  if(ysqmodn == test)
  {
    Serial.print("The current ICC matches. \n");
  }  
  else
  {  
    Serial.print(String(e));
    Serial.print("\n");
  }
  delay(500);
}
```

Comment: When you say "not working" what do you mean by that? Do you get unexpected results? If so, what is your actual and expected results?

Comment: It **does** work when `e==1`. For your info I posted the code below.

Answer (score 1):

It **does** work when `e==1`. When `e==0` the computation is trivial, since `s` and `v` fall out due to power of 0 always being 1. This is the code copied and altered only enough to get it to compile.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <math.h>

int random (int low, int high) {
    return low + rand() % (high - low);
}

int getGCD(int a, int b) {
    int c;
    while (a != 0)
    {
        c = a;
        a = b % a;
        b = c;
    }
    return b;
}

int getCoprime(int n) {
    int coprime;
    do
    {
        coprime = random(1, n);
    } 
    while (getGCD(n, coprime) != 1);
    return coprime;
}

int main(void) {
        int e, x, y, r, n, s, v, test, ysqmodn;

        srand((unsigned)time(NULL));
        n = 7 * 3;
        s = getCoprime(n);
        v = (s * s) % n;

        e = random(0, 2);
        r = random(1, n);

        printf("n=%d, s=%d, e=%d, r=%d\n", n,s,e,r);

        y = (r * (int)pow(s, e)) % n;
        x = (r * r) % n;

        ysqmodn = y * y % n;
        test = (x * (int)pow(v, e)) % n;

        if(ysqmodn == test)
            printf("The current ICC matches. \n");
        else
            printf("%d\n", e);

        return 0;
    }
```

Sample results:

```
n=21, s=2, e=1, r=2
The current ICC matches.

n=21, s=11, e=0, r=12
The current ICC matches.

n=21, s=8, e=1, r=14
The current ICC matches.

n=21, s=17, e=1, r=13
The current ICC matches.

n=21, s=1, e=0, r=9
The current ICC matches.

n=21, s=4, e=0, r=13
The current ICC matches.
```

Comment: I guess this is a better question for an arduino forum: i think the problem is with integer overflow or the fact that arduino int is 2 bytes.

Comment: @Haskelier or the implementation of `pow()`?

Comment: I don't really know. I think its a problem with rand(): when e = 0 it always works, when e = 1 it always works, but when e = rand(0, 2) it only works about half the time.

Comment: That's not what you originally said. I just tried it with `e=2` always, it worked every time.

Comment: The Linux `e=random(min,max)` returns `min <= e < max`, so I still don't know where your problem is. `e` won't be `2`.

Comment: im using the arduino rand(), which is inclusive in the beginning, exclusive at the end.

Comment: @Haskelier, isn't that what I put in the last comment?